# how to use retrieved from sql database

Tags: c#

i want the statment of how to use the retrieved data  from sql database table, i mean
i want to use the last cell of two columns from the same table with c#

Comment: please post your code attempt

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your table has following columns:

1. ID
2. Name

You can access second column "Name" as follows:

```
DataTable dtb=....;//Here your code returns DataTable

//suppose you want to set value of second column (Name) from 1st row on a label

label1.Text = dtb.Rows[0][1];

//OR

label1.Text = dtb.Rows[0]["Name"];

//OR if you want to use second column from all rows, say in a list

foreach(DataRow dr in dtb.Rows)
{
    list1.Items.Add(dr["Name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a SqlDataReader:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (reader.Read()) {
     int id = (int)reader["ID"]; // or reader.GetInt(0);
     string name = reader["Name"].ToString(); // or reader.GetString(1);
  }
  reader.Close();
}
```